# Validate list in marshmallow

Tags: python, python-3.6, marshmallow

currently I am using marshmallow schema to validate the request,
and I have this a list and I need to validate the content of it.

```py
class PostValidationSchema(Schema):
    checks = fields.List(
        fields.String(required=True)
    )
```

the checks field is a list it should only contain these specific values `["booking", "reservation", "flight"]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean to check the list only has those three elements in that order, then use `Equal` validator.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate


class PostValidationSchema(Schema):
    checks = fields.List(
        fields.String(required=True),
        validate=validate.Equal(["booking", "reservation", "flight"])
    )

schema = PostValidationSchema()

schema.load({"checks": ["booking", "reservation", "flight"]})  # OK
schema.load({"checks": ["booking", "reservation"]})  # ValidationError
```

If the list can have any number of elements and those can only be one of those three specific values, then use `OneOf` validator.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate


class PostValidationSchema(Schema):
    checks = fields.List(
        fields.String(
            required=True,
            validate=validate.OneOf(["booking", "reservation", "flight"])
        ),
    )

schema = PostValidationSchema()

schema.load({"checks": ["booking", "reservation", "flight"]})  # OK
schema.load({"checks": ["booking", "reservation"]})  # OK
schema.load({"checks": ["booking", "dummy"]})  # ValidationError
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jerome answer, I also figured out that if you need to do something which requires more logic you could do:

```
def validate_check(check: str):
  return check in ["booking", "reservation", "flight"]

class PostValidationSchema(Schema):
    checks = fields.List(
        fields.String(required=True, validate=validate_check)
    )
```

Or using lambda:

```py
class PostValidationSchema(Schema):
    checks = fields.List(
        fields.String(required=True, validate=lambda check: check in ["booking", "reservation", "flight"])
    )
```

Comment: +1 because those are good examples of what you could do for more complicated examples. You'd better use a builtin validator if one is available. Less code on your side, and it may have other benefits, like better auto-documentation in apispec for instance.