# Is there a way for testing for uniqueness of a field in a collection of records in marshmallow

Tags: marshmallow

Is there a standard way to validate the uniqueness of a field in a record upon loading?

For example, if validating for a unique id in the list below, the last two records in this structure would trigger a failure.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "stuff": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "stuff": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "stuff": "abc"
  }
]
```

I found a [comment](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/541) on an issue from 2016 suggesting that it is not, has anything changed in that time?

Related question:
[Validate list in marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180101/validate-list-in-marshmallow)

https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way as of today. The closest to a conversation about this would be in this PR: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/pull/1793.

It is not that hard to implement in your own code but we haven't been able yet to come up with a generic enough implementation.

Comment: In order to implement this yourself, see https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#schema-level-validation